# Windows 7 not able to boot after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 using a bootable USB (4GB) on my friend's laptop. Dell Inspiron 1510 (n series)

Initially, she approached me since Ubuntu was not able to be installed on her laptop. The problem was that her HDD was converted into a Dynamic disk. I used EaseUS to convert the disk into basic disk.

First time it gave me a small error and it didn't apply the changes on the computer yet (hadn't rebooted yet) but I closed EaseUS after the process finished and checked disk management, HDD was still dynamic. I repeated the process. This time, the entire process went smoothly and I installed Ubuntu 12.10 successfully as a dual boot.

After that, I couldn't boot into Windows 7
I can access the files from Ubuntu though.

She doesn't have a recovery disk and doesn't remember the version of Windows 7 (most probably Home Basic/Premium)

How can I find out the correct version? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you probably deleted the Windows boot partition (A small, ~200Mb partition that Windows needs to be able to boot). To my knowledge, the only way to fix this is with a Windows Recovery Disc (or USB). As for finding out which version of Windows you have, I'm not sure. Is she has over 4GB memory installed then she's probably using a 64bit version, but I'm not sure how to check which specific version without actually booting into Windows. Hopefully somebody else can shed some light on that.

Answer (score 0):

- Restore direct access to Windows : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader
- then restore the GRUB menu via Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair